# How can I see the application directly underneath a soft keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a soft keyboard that pipes data (not text) to a receiving intent. Is there any way to see the application/activity that the keyboard is currently overlaying? I am trying to preselect the intent action chooser and develop custom rules to get the data to go to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd answer my own question for this one. Here is the code that returns the activity from the top of the stack.

```
public String PullTop() {
  final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
  //Get the Activity Manager Object
  ActivityManager aManager = 
  (ActivityManager) self.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  //Get the list of running Applications
  List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> rapInfoList = aManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
  //Iterate all running apps to get their details
  for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo rapInfo : rapInfoList) {
    //error getting package name for this process so move on
    if (rapInfo.pkgList.length == 0)
      continue; 
    try {
      PackageInfo pkgInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(rapInfo.pkgList[0], PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
      Log.i("Package",pkgInfo.packageName);
      return pkgInfo.packageName;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      Log.d("", "NameNotFoundException :" + rapInfo.pkgList[0]);
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

To pipe the data to the right process just check for null and:

```
intent.setPackage(PullTop());
```